# Lookup-column that looks for sites in tenant?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, list, lookup-column, administration

Is it possible to create a lookup in a list that looks for sites in the tenant?

I am trying to make a project list, where each project is a new site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, No.

You cannot get the list of SharePoint sites in the tenant to show in lookup column values.

Using SharePoint lookup columns, information from one list (the source list) is shown in another list (the target list).

**Microsoft documentation**: [Create list relationships by using lookup columns](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-list-relationships-by-using-lookup-columns-80a3e0a6-8016-41fb-ad09-8bf16d490632)

Comment: I understand. Thank you!